# Why does $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!!}$ converge to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: summation, factorial

Why does:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!!}$$

converge to $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

I'm honestly not sure where to start.

Comment: Not sure how much that'll help, but you can start by expanding out:
$$\begin{align}
(2n+1)!! 
&= (2n+1)(2n-1)\dots 3\cdot 1
= \frac{(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)\dots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{(2n)(2n-2)\cdots2\cdot1}
\\&= \frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n(n-1 )\cdots1}
= \frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n n!}\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
From there, you can get things like
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!!}
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!^2}{(2n+1)!}2^n
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{\binom{2n}{n}(2n+1)}
$$

Comment: A slightly different take on the answer someone gave: can you figure out what the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!!}x^n$ represents? Can you evaluate that at $x=1$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I am not entirely sure, [given the closed-form expression of that function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(x%5En+n!)%2F(2+n%2B1)!!,+%7Bn,+0,+Infinity%7D%5D), that it'll lead to any immediate insight (?).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n!}{(2n+1)!!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2^n n!^2}{(2n+1)\cdot (2n)!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2^n}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2^n \Gamma(n+1)^2}{\Gamma(2n+2)}$$
can be written, through Euler's [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), also as
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}2^n\int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1-2x(1-x)}\stackrel{\text{symmetry}}{=}2\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{2\,dx}{1+(2x-1)^2} $$
or, through the substitution $x=\frac{1-z}{2}$, as
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2\,dz}{1+z^2}=2\arctan(1)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$

---

As an alternative, you may notice your series (related to the Taylor series of the arcsine function) is half the [Euler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) of [Gregory series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GregorySeries.html). See pages 20-21 of [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view), for instance.

Comment: That was quick.

Comment: @ClementC.: I recognized it on the spot since I have already included this identity in my notes :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for such a delay in accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Apply Euler transform to Leibniz fomula for $\pi$

Leibniz fomula is
$$
1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + ~..~ = \frac{\pi}{4}
$$

Euler transform is
$$
a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3 + ~..~ = \frac{a_0}{2} - \frac{\Delta a_0}{2^2} + \frac{\Delta^2 a_0}{2^3} - \frac{\Delta^3 a_0}{2^4} + ~..
$$
where $\Delta a_0 = a_1 - a_0$, $\Delta^2 a_0 = (a_2 - a_1) - (a_1-a_0) $,$\Delta^3a_0 = ((a_3-a_2)-(a_2-a_1)) - ((a_2-a_1)-(a_1-a_0))$, ..etc.

Proof:
Consider shift operator $T a_0 = a_1$, and difference operator $\Delta a_0 = a_1-a_0$. Then $\Delta = T-1$. Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3 + ~..~ &=& (1-T+T^2-T^3+~..)a_0 \\
&=& \frac{1}{1+T} a_0 = \frac{1}{2+\Delta} a_0\\
&=& \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\Delta}{2^2} + \frac{\Delta^2}{2^3} - ~..\right) a_0
\end{eqnarray}

Applying this to Leibniz fomula.
\begin{eqnarray}
a_0 &=& 1 \\
\Delta a_0 &=& - \frac{2 }{1\cdot 3} \\
\Delta^2 a_0 &=& \frac{2 \cdot 4}{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5} \\
\Delta^3 a_0 &=& - \frac{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6}{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7} \\
..
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{eqnarray}
1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + ~..~ = \frac{1}{2} \left(1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1 \cdot 2}{3 \cdot 5} + \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}{3 \cdot 5\cdot 7} + ~..\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{eqnarray}
Thus
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!!} = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

2. Use beta function related method.
   See
   $$
   \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^n dx = \frac{2^n n!}{(2n+1)!!}
   $$
   Proof:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   (x (1-x^2)^n)' &=& (1-x^2)^n - 2n x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1} \\
   &=& (1-x^2)^n + 2n (1-x^2)^{n-1} - 2n x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1} - 2n (1-x^2)^{n-1} \\
   &=&(1+2n)(1-x^2)^n - 2n (1-x^2)^{n-1}
   \end{eqnarray}
   Therefore
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^n dx = \frac{2 n}{2n+1}\int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{n-1} dx
   \end{eqnarray}
   Then the result readily follows. Then

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!!} &=&
\int_0^1 dx \left(1 + \frac{1-x^2}{2} + \frac{(1-x^2)^2}{4} + \frac{(1-x^2)^3}{8} + ~..\right) \\
&=& \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-\frac{1-x^2}{2}} dx \\
&=& \int_0^1 \frac{2dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score -1):

What about finding a function $f$ for which there exists an $x$ such that $f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$, calculating its Taylor series and using the Euler Transform for series?

Start with $a\tan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and search for the Taylor series of $a\tan(x)$:
$$a\tan(x)=f(x) = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)}x^n.$$

Looking at the Euler transform  gives us $$ \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)f\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) = \sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\sum _{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)}\right)x^n.$$

Using that  $$\sum _{k=0}^n {n \choose k}\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} = \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$$

We see that the series $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(2n+1)!!}  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = 
 2f(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Comment: Removing my downvote after the complete overhaul of the answer, but... seriously, the first sentence is not useful at all. It does not help in any way in figuring out what to do next, if one does not already know.

Comment: You're right. I will do better in the future :-) Thanks for removing the downvote.